# where is console.log file?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, filepath, console.log

I'writing an addon for Firefox... (and load it from URL tools "about:debugging#addons")

I try this code (from https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest):

```
function cancel(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Canceling: " + requestDetails.url);
  return {cancel: true};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  cancel,
  {urls: ["*://*.*.*/*"], types: ["image"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

This code and result is ok, is that i need ...But,how can I read the console.log ??
I don't found the file on my computer and no message are write on Firefox console ??

Comment: The messages are not written into a file. Maybe you've filtered the messages out of the console. Open the console, and check what have you filtered out using "Filter output". To see the logs, you've click to "Logs" active on the filter buttons.

Comment: Ok, is solved, it's very strange, the console activate by short-cut CTRL+SHIFT+C on firefox remain empty but the pop-up console activate by menu show logs !